# Fixing encoding error when exporting GeoPandas dataframe to Esri shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

When I try to export a list of geodataframe to esri shapefile like this:

```
out_path = os.path.join(out_folder, filename)
df.crs= "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"            
df.to_file(out_path, driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

It used to work fine but now it give this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 73: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'fiona._env.log_error'
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 73: invalid continuation byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\script.py", line 72, in <module>
    result.to_file(out_path, driver='ESRI Shapefile')
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 533, in to_file
    to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, index, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 191, in to_file
    filename, "w", driver=driver, crs_wkt=crs_wkt, schema=schema, **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py", line 398, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 267, in open
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.session.start(self, **kwargs)
  File "fiona\ogrext.pyx", line 1147, in fiona.ogrext.WritingSession.start
  File "fiona\ogrext.pyx", line 619, in fiona.ogrext.Session.get_schema
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 9: unexpected end of data
```

I don't have any problem if write: dt.to_file(out_path, driver='geojson')

Comment: What is `dt` ?!

Comment: It's an mistak. It is df. I will correct it

Comment: Could you add more information about `df` (dtypes, head, etc.), especially about any columns that might contain non-ASCII characters? Have you tried specifying the encoding directly in the `to_file` call?

Comment: Thank you Mr Jan, I found that the error was because a special character in one of the field names. it was a "ê" letter.

Comment: You need to specify the encoding `df.to_file(out_path, driver='ESRI Shapefile,encoding = 'utf-8')`

Comment: Thank you very much